# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Whenever I run my program I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

```
 Sub admininfoo()
    Dim q As String = "Select * from Table2 where AdminPassword=" & AdminLogin.TextBox1.Text
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(q, connection)
    Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    reader.Read()

    AdminInterface.Label2.Text = reader("Name")


    reader.Close()
End Sub
```

btw I am using Visual Basic 2013 and Microsoft Access Database

Comment: Then why did you tag this question as C#?

Answer (score 0):

You are not sanitizing your inputs. If your password has an '?' character in it, the `OleDb` provider will interpret it as a parameter that you will need pass in, which you should be doing anyways, to prevent any injection.

Use the `OleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue` method to add your parameter.

```
 Dim q As String = "Select * from Table2 where AdminPassword=?" 
 Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(q, connection)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AdminPassword", AdminLogin.TextBox1.Text)
 Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```